# Кастомизация PopupWindow

Tags: android

Очень интересно, каким образом можно сделать такой  PopupWindow:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Как можно такое сделать?**

Answer (score 2):

1. Прозрачный фон
2. На нём растягивающаяся картинка
3. На ней кнопки